# Solution to capture an image using webdriver. Does any one has better solution for this?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to share code to capture the screen shot of all  tag in selenium webdriver

1. get all `<img>` tag in list

   ```
   List<WebElement> image = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
   int i=1;
   ```
2. Use this:

   ```
   for(WebElement allImages : image){

       //Download image
       File screen=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       int width=allImages.getSize().getWidth();
       int height=allImages.getSize().getHeight();
       BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(screen);
       BufferedImage dest=img.getSubimage(allImages.getLocation().getX(), allImages.getLocation().getY(), width, height);
       ImageIO.write(dest, "png", screen); 
       File file=new File("/Users/h-disk/Desktop/folder-name/abc"+i+".png");
   ```

Using this code you can capture all `<img>`s

Comment: this is the best solution for tester community, its already verified from developer and its more than OK. 
If you have any better idea then welcome.

Comment: It doesn't matter how good this code is, this is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use frameworks like Gallio or RobotFramework to improve this process